# Localized text into aria-label HTML

Tags: html, localization, wai-aria

I have various `aria-label` descriptions throughout my page and I wanted to use text that I already have saved in my localization file. I am not sure how I can assign a string from my localized file into my

```
aria-label="localizedFile_description_string"
```

Typically I would use a localized string as such:

```
<h2 l10n="PageTitle_header"></h2>
```

I am not sure how that syntax would be for `aria-label=" "`.

I tried

```
aria-labelledby="labelString"
<div id="labelString" l10n="string_from_localized_file"></div>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You might have to give us a little more information. How is this string written onto the page and what is not working? Is this ASP.NET? Or plain HTML? Javascript?

Comment: @Remy i have list of strings in a .resx file which i use to pull info to display in my html. this is for an angular 2 project. My problem is i am not sure how i can reference my .resx file to point to the label text i want to use to populate my aria-label tag. Also is it true that aria-label text automatically get converted to whatever language/program the user is using and that localization is not needed for aria-labels?

Answer (score 0):

It obviously depends a bit on how you named your resource files, but assuming you called the file `resource.resx` and you have an entry that is called `labelString`:

```
<button aria-label="<%$ Resources:Resource, labelString %>" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
<div id="myId" l10n="<%$ Resources:Resource, labelString %>"></div>
```

I've never seen `aria-label` on it's own. I think it's usually part of an html element.

Comment: yes you are correct, aria-label is always part of an html element. I wasn't sure how to bind a string from the resource file into aria-label. What does this syntax stand for: `<%$`?

Comment: Thats the ASP.NET syntax for resources. Are you using WebForms or Razer Views?

Comment: I am actually using angular 2 + typescript and html.

Comment: I assumed since you use a .resx file, that you are using asp.net. Are you still using asp.net *.resx files?